# SSRS Reporting error in Total

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have Developed a new SSRS report. I added a new tablix in it and in that tablix added two columns called "Total Incidents logged" and "Total Security Incidents logged".I gave row visibility and mention the following expression.
=iif(Fields!SecurtiyIncidents.Value = 0,true,false)

So i hide those rows in which values of security Incidents contains 0. But the problem is, in total column of Total Incidents logged, it contains the hide values also. I googled and found only those answers which contains only one Column and people gave row visibility. But in my case there are 2 columns.

For better understanding, i have added images. In first image, the normal table is there with total

in second picture, given row filtration on Security Incidents Logged, i.e =iif(Fields!SecurtiyIncidents.Value = 0,true,false)(So i hide those rows in which values of security Incidents contains 0) but if you see total of Incidents logged, it not changed. :(

Could anyone please help me out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are putting two different values in one row.
You are telling SSRS to hide that row if one specific value in that row is zero.
When that value is zero, the whole row is hidden and you are wondering why?

Either put the values in different rows, set the ***column*** visibility using your expression above or simply set the value of the text box to be `=iif(Fields!SecurtiyIncidents.Value = 0,"",Fields!SecurtiyIncidents.Value)`

Comment: I want to Hide that row and i hide it. But my concern is, after hiding that particular row, i am getting hidden values added into Total Text box which comes under Another column called Total Incidents Logged.(I.e. Logged Incidents)

Comment: If you don't want it in your total then you need to exclude the row from your source dataset rather than simply hide it in your report table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding each row that has zero values in one or both fields you can use a conditional `SUM` in the total row as follows.

For No of Incidents Logged column use:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!SecurityIncidents.Value>0,
Fields!IncidentsLogged.Value,
0))
```

For No of Security Incidents Logged use:

```
=SUM(Fields!SecurityIncidents.Value)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @PushkarGhatpande, I've updated the expressions, try them again.

Comment: it still not works. :( For logged incidents total, its taking security incidents total.

Comment: @PushkarGhatpande, I am pretty sure the expression works in the described scenario, what are you getting in the Incidents Logged total? Also if it would be better if you add a screenshot of your tablix.

Comment: @ alejandro zuleta: Whenever i am giving your mentioned expression in Logged Incidents total(i.e. =SUM(IIF(Fields!SecurityIncidents.Value>0,
Fields!IncidentsLogged.Value,
0))), its giving me the Security incidents total. i.e. for E.g.in above second image, it gives me 500 in logged incidents total instead of 2520. I have added my tablix images for your better understanding. :)

Comment: @PushkarGhatpande, Is the total row in the scope of any row group? If so, delete the total row and create it again outside the scope of any group. then try my expression again.

Comment: Its Outside Only.

Comment: @ alejandro zuleta: Still no success mate. :(

Comment: @PushkarGhatpande, provide a sample dataset similar to your in order to help you.

Comment: There is no issue related dataset. Its related to expression only. Because of the dataset, the tablix values are populating correctly as i validated in SSMS only. So no problem in dataset. :)

Comment: @PushkarGhatpande, Did your try to delete the tablix and recreate it again from scratch. It is possible you set some property to the tablix resulting in this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @PushkarGhatpande, In that case and without check your tablix I suggest you filter the tablix or the dataset instead of hiding the rows which `Fields!SecurityIncidents.Value = 0`. In the Tablix Properties window or DataSet properties window there is a **FILTER** where you can specify a filter to include only the rows which  `Fields!SecurityIncidents.Value > 0`, then the total should be correctly calculated. Check [this example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2597/dataset-and-tablix-filtering-in-sql-server-reporting-services/).

Comment: But after doing this, it affecting to complete tablix. i.e. as per you mentioned, i removed hidden expression and give filer to table or dataset with the Fields!SecurityIncidents.Value > 0. But in logged incidents rows and total, shows same values as Security Incidents.

Comment: @PushkarGhatpande, What do you mean with "shows same values as Security Incidents"? If you filter the DataSet/Tablix you just have to use `SUM(Fields!SecurityIncidents.Value)` and `SUM(Fields!IncidentsLogged.Value)`

Comment: Still no Luck Mate. :( its really frustrating. :( @alejandro zuleta

Answer (score 0):

Filter the tablix:
Fields!SecurtiyIncidents.Value <> 0

Hiding the row only modify the display, the calcs/totals remains normal.

Comment: But whenever you are giving any such expression or filtration for tablix, it will affect the whole tablix not for single column.